# Android ListView Views Not Being Conditioned

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I am using a Custom Array Adapter to populate my Chat Screen. To this, I am using a condition to see who is the sender, and depending on that, I am assigning the design (Whether red(Received Message) or blue(Sent Message).

However, when I first send the message, it does not check the condition and applies the default layout to the chat message.

And from then on, subsequently, it chooses the last state of layout to display the message without checking whether its the sent message, or received message.( Example, if I received a message, it will set RED as per condition, but after that as I send the message, it automatically assigns it red, without checking the condition(it should be assigned blue, since its a sent message) ).

Here is the code of ChatAdapter:

```
   import com.tanishqsharma.unanswered.dbHandler.PrefManager;


import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Tanishq on 16-06-2016.
 */
public class ChatAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MessageObject> {

    ArrayList<MessageObject> local_obj;
    PrefManager prefManager;
    FontGenerator FG;
    String sender;
    Animation fadein;
    Animation fade_out;
    String message;

    public ChatAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MessageObject> passed_obj) {
        super(context, R.layout.chat_message ,passed_obj);
        prefManager = new PrefManager(context);
        FG = new FontGenerator(context);
        fadein = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.fade_in);
        fade_out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.fade_out);
        this.local_obj = passed_obj;
    }

    static class ViewHolderChatMessage
    {
        LinearLayout layoutchat;
        LinearLayout mainChatLayout;
        TextView message;
        TextView datetime;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;

        final ViewHolderChatMessage viewHolderChatMessage;
        if(view==null)
        {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_message, parent, false);
            viewHolderChatMessage = new ViewHolderChatMessage();
            viewHolderChatMessage.message = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.chatbubble);
            viewHolderChatMessage.layoutchat = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.layoutchat);
            viewHolderChatMessage.mainChatLayout = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.mainChatLayout);
            viewHolderChatMessage.datetime = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.DateTime);
            view.setTag(viewHolderChatMessage);
        }
        else
        {
            viewHolderChatMessage = (ViewHolderChatMessage) view.getTag();
        }

        viewHolderChatMessage.mainChatLayout.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
        message = local_obj.get(position).getMessage();
        viewHolderChatMessage.message.setText(message);
        viewHolderChatMessage.message.setTypeface(FG.getRobotoRegular());

        viewHolderChatMessage.datetime.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        sender = local_obj.get(position).getSender();

        if(sender!=null)
        {
            if(sender.equals(prefManager.getUserMobile()))
            {
                viewHolderChatMessage.message.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_chat_blue);
                viewHolderChatMessage.layoutchat.setGravity(Gravity.END);
                viewHolderChatMessage.datetime.setText(local_obj.get(position).getDate());
                viewHolderChatMessage.datetime.setGravity(Gravity.END);

            }
            else
            {
                viewHolderChatMessage.message.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_chat_red);
                viewHolderChatMessage.layoutchat.setGravity(Gravity.START);
                viewHolderChatMessage.datetime.setText(local_obj.get(position).getDate());
                viewHolderChatMessage.datetime.setGravity(Gravity.START);

            }
        }

        viewHolderChatMessage.message.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                viewHolderChatMessage.datetime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                viewHolderChatMessage.datetime.startAnimation(fadein);
                viewHolderChatMessage.datetime.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        viewHolderChatMessage.datetime.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        viewHolderChatMessage.datetime.startAnimation(fade_out);
                    }
                }, 3000);
            }
        });


        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(MessageObject object) {
        super.add(object);

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Example:

[image: As you can see, the first message is coming default on the left side even though according to the condition, it should come on the right side. Been trying different things like notifysetdatachanged() but it is not working as well.]

As you can see, the first message is coming default on the left side even though according to the condition, it should come on the right side. Been trying different things like notifysetdatachanged() but it is not working as well.

[image: The second error as I mentioned, it is adding the chat messages to the adapter based on the last viewholder sender I guess.]

The second error as I mentioned, it is adding the chat messages to the adapter based on the last viewholder sender I guess.

Thanks for all the help possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem by using this method. Since I was not using push, it was creating a save request everytime and by the time my adapter/receiver class reflected, it onlly read the null value.

> ### push()